# CSS3 Transition Not Working

Tags: html, css, transition

I'm trying to make a transition for my social media buttons. I have applied a valid transition effect, but it wont work :(

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zu3sP/

CSS:

```
.social-spin {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.social-spin:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn-social blue-btn" type="button">
    <img class="social-spin" src="http://i.imgur.com/sz3UXCt.png">
</button>
```

Comment: It is working fine in my browser. I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: How can I get it to work in firefox do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are : http://jsfiddle.net/Zu3sP/2/ 
Just give a initial rotation :

```
.social-spin{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, im in firefox also and doesnt seem to work, I will check chrome

Comment: @user2598957 fixed! i've updated the link in my answer , check it out

Comment: @user2598957 it was `.social-spin:hover` , i've turned it into: `.btn-social:hover .social-spin ` . it was not correct , strange that in other browsers it worked at all

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using, it seems to be working fine for me in Chrome.

In firefox the hover appears to only work with anchors and not images.

If you change the declaration like so it works.

```
.btn-social:hover .social-spin { }
```